# Database design with many users to each organization

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am designing a product that is mainly to be used by small organizations. The idea is for every member of the organization to have their own accounts (known as subaccounts). At the same time, there needs to be data that can be accessed by anyone with that organization. I am trying to decide between two courses of action.

### Separate Table for Organizations

In this design, there would be a `organizations` table and a `users` table. The `users` would be connected to `organizations` via foreign key, and the shared data would use the foreign id of the organization.

### User Conglomerate

Here an additional field in the `users` table would point to another row in the table (the parent) that represents the primary account for the organization and is linked to all the shared data.

Which approach would be superior in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches seem reasonable and workable, but I would lean towards having a separate table for organizations as ultimately the idea of an 'organization' is different to that of an 'user'. You may need to have different attributes for an organization than you would a user (e.g. you may need to have more than one 'superuser' for an organization at some stage), and so having this data in a separate table would make it (a) easier to code against (b) more extensible and future-proof (c) more efficient and normalized in storage.

Comment: That does make since. If the primary user changed, only one thing would need to change in the organizations table.